# Super Mario Run on multiple android tablets?

Tags: android, super-mario-run

I purchased the full Super Mario Run game from the google play store and installed it on my daughter's android tablet.  However, when I try to restore purchases on my son's tablet (signed in to my google play account also), it says there is no content to restore.  I also tried to re buy the game on his tablet and it wouldn't let me because I already own it....
Any way to get it unlocked on the second tablet?